# Does SPIM (MIPS simulator) always call the "main" label first?

Tags: mips, mips32, spim

I load up 2 files into SPIM in order.

File 1:

```
.globl getCount
.data
count:          .word 50

.text
getCount:       lw $v0, count($0)
                jr $ra
```

File 2:

```
 .text
  main:  #code to call the getCount label and print the result stored in $v0
         jr $ra
```

When SPIM merges the 2 files, it always seem to know to run at adress `main` and use the `jr $ra` in `main` to exit the program after printing the result. It doesn't run at address `getCount` and exit program with that method's `jr $ra`.

So I'm asking, is the `main` label a reseerved label that SPIM detects to run first or maybe that `main` chunk is put above the address of other ones?

Comment: Inspect the text segment and look at what code the simulator places before your code.

Comment: Okay, I see a `jal main` before my code, so the `main` label is special. I'm assuming if I replaced my `main` label with `main2`, it wouldn't work.